# Redirect "robots.txt" on specific domain

Tags: apache-2.4, configuration, rewrite, httpd, robots.txt

I want to redirect all requests on "robots.txt" if the domain contains ".our-internal-devel-domain.de". It should be server-wide, because when we develop a website and publish it over our test-domain, I dont want to have it on google so i want to deliver a deny-all robots.txt.

For testing purposes, these domains do exist even after launching the project, so if the domain doesn't contain our devel-domain, the normal robots.txt should be served.

For example some pseudocode, but I didn't manage to use it with mod_rewrite or Alias in apache conf:

```
if current_domain.contains("our-internal-devel-domain.de") && querystring == "robots.txt" 
  deliver("/path/to/global/deny/robots.txt")
```

Comment: What is your Apache configuration?

Answer (score 1):

This can be as simple as

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName our-internal-devel-domain.de>
  Alias /robots.txt /path/to/global/deny/robots.txt 
</VirtualHost>
```